# Traceback (most recent call last): Adafruit BME 280 Sensor

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, adafruit

I have succesfully installed Adafruit_Gpio package and when i try to run the example file of the bme sensor provided by adafruit, i get the following error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rpi3/Adafruit_Python_BME280/example.py", line 3, in <module>
    sensor = BME280(mode=BME280_OSAMPLE_8)
  File "/home/rpi3/Adafruit_Python_BME280/Adafruit_BME280.py", line 88, in __init__
    self._device = i2c.get_i2c_device(address, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/Adafruit_GPIO-1.0.3-py3.5.egg/Adafruit_GPIO/I2C.py", line 64, in get_i2c_device
    return Device(address, busnum, i2c_interface, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/Adafruit_GPIO-1.0.3-py3.5.egg/Adafruit_GPIO/I2C.py", line 97, in __init__
    self._bus = Adafruit_PureIO.smbus.SMBus(busnum)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/Adafruit_PureIO/smbus.py", line 97, in __init__
    self.open(bus)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/Adafruit_PureIO/smbus.py", line 122, in open
    self._device = open('/dev/i2c-{0}'.format(bus), 'r+b', buffering=0)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/i2c-1'
```

I am on xubuntu for rpi-3 i have run apt-get udpate and restarted the machine neither worked.

Comment: Νο one,has something to say :(?

Comment: show your code also...

Comment: Have you tried this?
 https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43923/i2c-not-working-on-rpi-2-b

Comment: My code is the example from adafruit as stated:https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_BME280/blob/master/Adafruit_BME280_Example.py(just added parenthesis to print)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution with a little help form the comments.
Especially **for xubuntu** the steps are:

`sudo raspi-config`

Select:

`3 Interfacing Options`

Select:

`P4 I2C`

and `YES`